# Powershell - how to detect an imminent windows re-boot?

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-11

I have a windows PowerShell script that needs to run 24/7.

Occasionally windows requires an automated update and re-boot. Is there any way I can detect when this is about to happen? I'd like to ensure the script does an orderly shutdown, rather than be abruptly terminated.

I'm not looking for a weeks notice of a re-boot, but five minutes warning would be long enough to ensure the script closes various database tables, and does some basic housekeeping rather than simply falling over in an ugly heap.

UPDATE - I know there are a lot of web articles describing how to detect when an update and/or reboot is pending, but none (that I can find) actually pin it down to a time. Some updates/reboots remain pending for hours or days. I'm looking for a flag or notification that '*this server will reboot within the next ten minutes*' or something similar.

Comment: There are a lot of articles on the web about getting pending reboots [example](https://blog.icewolf.ch/archive/2020/07/03/check-for-pending-reboot-with-powershell.aspx). Mostly you need to read some regkeys.

Comment: Windows Updates aside, any admin can always trigger reboots instantly with no chance for recovery; they can also schedule reboots in any number of ways. Your best bet is to ensure your script assumes it can be terminated at any time, and always do startup recovery in accordance with that policy, because that way it will "never fail". Also consider not having a PowerShell script for your 24/7 needs as it can be terminated without warning far more easily than a service or regular application could (those at least get notifications before they close, unlike terminal sessions).

Comment: From my understanding, depending on the nature of the shutdown, Windows will tell WinForms based app to shutdown and wait from them to finish, causing the Form's [Shutdown Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#application-startup-and-shutdown-events) to fire.  I have no experience in testing this, not sure if there is a time limit allowed for shutdown, and not sure if there is some method for trying to force windows to allow the WinForms app to do its proper shutdown.

Comment: Also, you can create WinForms apps in PowerShell, but I haven't tested if the shutdown events are fired when Windows is shutting down.